# jQuery: How to loop throught of kendo ui dropdowns by class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to get all `id` and `selected values` of kendo ui dropdowns by class name

I have tryed things such as the following with no success

```
var values = [];
$('.payType option').each(function () { 
    debugger;
    values.push( $(this).attr('value') );
});
```

The UI is genarated via a loop

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      <kendo-DropDownList id="@item.ItemId" 
              class="payType" value="@item.ItemValue"
              datavaluefield="Value" datatextfield="Text" 
              auto-bind="true" 
              bind-to="@ViewData["List"] as IEnumerable<ComboModel>"/>
   }
```

So how can i select all dropdownLists by the class name `payType` and later on,

add the selected id names and values into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the widget instance to play with:

```
$('select.payType').each(function() {
    let selectedOption = $(this).data('kendoDropDownList').dataItem();
    // Play with selectedOption as you like
});
```

`selectedOption` will hold all data you need.

[Demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/asuLaCoT)